# rails activerecord includes 3 levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have these associations

```
class Incident < Activerecord::Base
   belongs_to :building

class Building < Activerecord::Base
   has_many :incidents
   belongs_to :contact

class Contact < Activerecord::Base
    has_many :buildings    
    belongs_to :company

class Company < Activerecord::Base
    has_many :contacts
```

I want to make a keyword search on incidents. This search should also look for companies associated to the incidents.

Therefore, I created this method

```
def self.filtered
      includes(:building => :contact => :company).where("lower(unaccent(incidents.description)) ilike lower(unaccent('%#{q}%')) or lower(unaccent(companies.name)) ilike lower(unaccent('%#{q}%'))")
end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError - Association named 'company' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

I don't know why but the "includes" method can have two levels of association but not three levels.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Just a wild shot: But can you try `includes(:building => {:contact => :company})`

Comment: Hope you need to use :through association. refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Hi Benjamin, that's thé Answer. I don't know why I didn't think about it. Silly me... Thanks!